# How to get existing Hive table delimiter

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is there any way to know the stored hive tables delimiter? I tried Describe extended but no use.. I have searched a lot, not yet getting the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am seeing by using `describe extended table` command

example:

```
hive> create table difdelimiter (id int, name string) 
      row format delimited 
      fields terminated by ',';

hive> describe extended difdelimiter; 
OK id                   int     
   name                 string                                      
   Detailed Table Information   Table(tableName:difdelimiter, dbName:default, owner:cloudera, createTime:1439375349, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:id, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:name, type:string, comment:null)], location:hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/difdelimiter, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=,, field.delim=,}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], parameters:{transient_lastDdlTime=1439375349}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)  Time taken: 0.154 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Here is the information about delimiter

```
parameters:{serialization.format=,, field.delim=,}
```

Adding as per the comments

```
hive> create table tb3 (id int, name string) row format delimited fields terminated by '/t';
OK
Time taken: 0.09 seconds
hive> describe extended tb3;
OK
id                      int                                         
name                    string                                      

Detailed Table Information  Table(tableName:tb3, dbName:default, owner:cloudera, createTime:1439377591, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:id, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:name, type:string, comment:null)], location:hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/tb3, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=/t, field.delim=/t}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], parameters:{transient_lastDdlTime=1439377591}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE) 
Time taken: 0.125 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)

parameters:{serialization.format=/t, field.delim=/t})
```

Comment: field.delim always displays , even though im using field delimiter as "/t", please check it.

Answer (score 9):

Other answers are correct in the sense that you would get the field delimiter if it is other than default. However, I don't see it if the delimiter is the default one, which is Control-A character or "\01" in ASCII

Comment: This is the correct answer IMHO, if yo don't give a default delimiter, it is ctrl-A. if you want to type the delimiter, ctrl + shift + a will do the trick and it's better than \t or ,

Answer (score 7):

Try running a "**show create table**" command and it will show you the delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute the **describe extended your_table_name** command you will get this info in the last part (Detailed Table Information) - just search for **field.delim**.

However that result set is not very well formatted and a more user-friendly approach is **show create table your_table_name**.